# Merge two dataframe based on a column with different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes on one column which is date.
But, the problem is that in one dataframe the date column type is `string`, and in another one, the type of the date is `datetime.date`.

The date in df1 is an integer, then I have use the following code to change it to YYYY-DD-MM

```
df1['date'] = df1['date'].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp) #change to YYYY-DD-MM HH-MM-SS

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date #change to datetime.date

df1['date'] = df1['date'].strftime('%Y-%d-%m') #change to string which does not work
```

Then, when I want to merge, the results for me is an empty dataframe. Here is a simple example. **[![Here the two dates are string. I could not assign the datetime.date to a date in this example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['a'] = [ '2012-01-02',  '2013-03-02' ]
df1['b'] = [ 2, 9]

df2['a'] = [ '2012-02-05',  '2013-03-02' ]
df2['b'] = [ 4, 7]
```

Here is the dataframe which I want.

[image]

Comment: did you try converting the string to a date?

Comment: Yes. My dataframe is very large and it seems that pd can not convert a column to string. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Looks like you may be doing the conversion wrong... Can you add the code that does the conversion to the question?

Comment: I've just update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly convert your date column to string: `df1['a'] = df1['a'].astype(str)`
From what I tested it gives the same format but you don't control it.

To control it you can apply the transformation: `df1['a'] = df1['a'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%d-%m'))`

Or you could change the other df to a date if it is a string in the format `YYYY-MM- DD` as you have in your small example: `df2['a'] = df2['a'].apply(datetime.fromisoformat)`